# MongoDB in Virtuozzo (OpenVZ)

Tags: mongodb, openvz, virtuozzo

My Server is hosted on HostEurope, a virtual server

uname -a prompts

**Linux lvps176-28-21-237.dedicated.hosteurope.de 2.6.18-028stab095.1 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 20:15:15 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

They are running OpenVZ. According to the support of HostEurope, an up to date version of Virtuozzo, but reading the version history on OpenVZ, this version is old, frozen and won't be maintained any more. Who is right?

My actual problem is that I want to run a MongoDB, but I am confronted with this OpenVZ problem explained here:

[Crashes reported on OpenVZ](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1121)

So, what can I do? Is there any chance to solve this Out-Of-Memory issue in MongoDB on OpenVZ in this version or do I have to find an other hosting company?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not in the current version of OpenVZ. If you see at the bottom of that thread link you posted, there is a suggested solution for the new OpenVZ (RHEL6 or higher).

Answer (score 0):

What about using ulimit eg

ulimit -Sv 500000

limiting the process to 500GB